# (Unity ML-agent) If I change the reward for an action, would it be better to do training all over again?

Tags: tensorflow, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

For example, let's asume that **Reward** for an action was a **negative** reward, and **Agent** was very very **well trained to avoid that action**.

In this situation, if I change the reward for that action to a **positive reward** and continue with the previous training, would it be difficult to expect the positive reward for that action?

If so, would it be better to start training all over again?